# Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found in android studio gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have included a sub-project "android-ngn-stack" in my project and my settings.gradle file looks like:

```
include 'android-ngn-stack'
project(':android-ngn-stack').projectDir = new File('../android-ngn-stack')
include ':app'
```

And the build.gradle file contains:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have tried invalidate cashes.But the error is still there.Will you suggest me your idea to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found

It happens when a module doens't have the `build.gradle` file.

Check if there are these files:

```
app\build.gradle
android-ngn-stack\build.gradle
```